# while loop does not work properly java

Tags: java, loops, io

In the following code for continuing the program user should press y character
but when  I press  y the loop terminate

```
public class JavaFile
{

    int i = 0;
    public void systemIO()throws java.io.IOException {
        System.out.println("Enter the character");
        i = System.in.read();
        System.out.println("the character Enter by the user : "+(char)i);
        System.out.println("the assci vlue "+i);
    }
    public void cntApp()throws java.io.IOException{
        char cnt = 'y';
        while(cnt =='y'){
            systemIO();
            System.out.println("press 'y'  if you want continue");
            cnt = (char)System.in.read(); 
            System.out.println("The Entery value   "+cnt);
        }

    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try{
        new JavaFile().cntApp();
    }catch(java.io.IOException ioExe){
        System.out.println(ioExe);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Minor point: consider a `do {} while ();` loop instead - you're guaranteed one iteration that way. Also, adding `System.out.println(Character.getName(cnt));` to your loop should show you exactly why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7681047/3898076).

You can add below line add the end of `systemIO()` and `cntApp()` method i.e. after the `System.in.read()` method call.

```
System.in.skip(System.in.available());
```

So your methods will look like this.

```
public void systemIO() throws java.io.IOException {
    System.out.println("Enter the character");
    i = System.in.read();
    System.out.println("the character Enter by the user : " + (char) i);
    System.out.println("the assci vlue " + i);
    System.in.skip(System.in.available());
}

public void cntApp() throws java.io.IOException {
    char cnt = 'y';
    while (cnt == 'y') {
        systemIO();
        System.out.println("press 'y'  if you want continue");
        cnt = (char) System.in.read();
        System.out.println("The Entery value   " + cnt);
        System.in.skip(System.in.available());
    }
}
```

**Note:** But using [`Scanner(System.in)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11871792/3898076) is better approach then using `System.in.read()` directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you run it in debug :

```
while(cnt =='y'){
        systemIO();
        System.out.println("press 'y'  if you want continue");
        cnt = (char)System.in.read(); 
        System.out.println("The Entery value   "+cnt);
}
```

You'll see that

```
cnt = (char)System.in.read();
```

return '\r', correspond to the validation by enter.

So, i will use a Scanner instead and it will be something like that :

```
public class JavaFile {
    int i = 0;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void systemIO()throws java.io.IOException {
        System.out.println("Enter the character");
        i = reader.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("the character Enter by the user : "+(char)i);
        System.out.println("the assci vlue "+i);
    }
    public void cntApp()throws java.io.IOException{
        char cnt = 'y';
        while(cnt =='y'){
            systemIO();
            System.out.println("press 'y'  if you want continue");
            cnt = reader.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println("The Entery value   "+cnt);
        }

    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try{
            new JavaFile().cntApp();
        }catch(java.io.IOException ioExe){
            System.out.println(ioExe);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In systematIO method,   after pressing the enter,  character  works fine
And show the value, but in cntApp method it's not 
we have two same methods whic act different in System.in

Comment: not really, all the characters entered are in a buffer

Comment: with System.in i think the only way is to read until is to read it until it's null. That's the reason why i use Scanner object.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the keyboard input is buffered and the following code is getting line-terminator/null value that causes the while-loop to terminate.

```
cnt = (char)System.in.read();
```

Try refactoring the code using Scanner class instead of System.in.read()

```
import java.util.Scanner;    

public class JavaFile {
        private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
...

    public void cntApp() throws java.io.IOException {

        String line = "y";
        while ("y".equals(line)) {
            systemIO();
            System.out.println("press 'y'  if you want continue");
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("The Entery value   " + line);
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
...
```

Comment: Is there any way we flush () keyboard entry buffer?

Comment: Consider the combination of skip() and available() methods as suggested by @Naman Gala

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your `cntApp` method to use a Scanner and take the first character entered

```
public void cntApp() throws java.io.IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    char cnt = 'y';
    while (cnt == 'y') {
        systemIO();
        System.out.println("press 'y'  if you want continue");
        cnt = in.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("The Enter value   " + cnt);
    }
}
```

Comment: They could, but *why* does that solve their issue? It would be helpful to explain what the problem actually is before offering a solution to it.